# Blurry legends in highcharts export pdf

Tags: highcharts

I have an application in which I am using highcharts v2.3.2 . When I try to export a chart as pdf, the legends appear as blurry. I tried to reproduce it on jsfiddle and it seems that it can be reproduced on any example on highcharts demo page as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/9PyUp/

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'spline'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Snow depth in the Vikjafjellet mountain, Norway'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'An example of irregular time data in Highcharts JS'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
            month: '%e. %b',
            year: '%b'
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Snow depth (m)'
        },
        min: 0
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                Highcharts.dateFormat('%e. %b', this.x) +': '+ this.y +' m';
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Winter 2007-2008',
        // Define the data points. All series have a dummy year
        // of 1970/71 in order to be compared on the same x axis. Note
        // that in JavaScript, months start at 0 for January, 1 for February etc.
        data: [
            [Date.UTC(1970,  9, 27), 0   ],
            [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 10), 0.6 ],
            [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 18), 0.7 ],
            [Date.UTC(1970, 11,  2), 0.8 ],
            [Date.UTC(1970, 11,  9), 0.6 ],
            [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 16), 0.6 ],
            [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 28), 0.67],
            [Date.UTC(1971,  0,  1), 0.81],
            [Date.UTC(1971,  0,  8), 0.78],
            [Date.UTC(1971,  0, 12), 0.98],
            [Date.UTC(1971,  0, 27), 1.84],
            [Date.UTC(1971,  1, 10), 1.80],
            [Date.UTC(1971,  1, 18), 1.80],
            [Date.UTC(1971,  1, 24), 1.92],
            [Date.UTC(1971,  2,  4), 2.49],
            [Date.UTC(1971,  2, 11), 2.79],
            [Date.UTC(1971,  2, 15), 2.73],
            [Date.UTC(1971,  2, 25), 2.61],
            [Date.UTC(1971,  3,  2), 2.76],
            [Date.UTC(1971,  3,  6), 2.82],
            [Date.UTC(1971,  3, 13), 2.8 ],
            [Date.UTC(1971,  4,  3), 2.1 ],
            [Date.UTC(1971,  4, 26), 1.1 ],
            [Date.UTC(1971,  5,  9), 0.25],
            [Date.UTC(1971,  5, 12), 0   ]
        ]
    }]
});
```

Comment: Please update it with Link.

Comment: I have added the link as well. Please have a look.

Comment: check the answer i posted.It works fine.

Comment: Thanks Vaibhav, It works perfectly. I only need to add background color to the chart with linear gradient and it fixes the bug. Do you know why this issue is arising ?

Comment: I think this is only because Highcharts.theme is not added to the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated Link for your example can be found [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jvaibhav/9PyUp/2/).

I added  `var highchartsOptions = Highcharts.setOptions(Highcharts.theme);` to it.Remove the things that are not required from Highcharts.theme